# Network Card Driver Issue ESXi 5

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I have a Silicom PXG4BPi Quad Port Gigabit PCI-X 4 GB ports NIC.
Intel 82546
Running VMware ESXi 5.0.0 Build 623860

HP Proliant DL140 G3

2x Xeon 5160 3.00GHz

12 GB mem

Now I have gone to the [Silicom PXG4BPi](http://www.silicom-usa.com/Networking_Bypass_Adapters/PXG4BPi-Quad_Port_Copper_Gigabit_Ethernet_PCI-X_Bypass_Server_Adapter_Intel_based_58) page. and downloaded the drivers for the card.

I installed the vib for EXSi 5.0
net-bpvm-2.0.1.13.3-1OEM.500.0.0.472560.x86_64.vib

rebooted and ran

```
esxcli software vib list | grep bpvm
```

Output

```
net-bpvm              2.0.1.13.3-1OEM.500.0.0.472560      Silicom  VMwareCertified   2012-07-31
```

So it is installed

But I yet it isn't showing the card being mounted.

I have tried to run `esxcfg-vswitch -L bpvm0 vSwitchX`
and get

```
Failed to add uplink bpvm0 to vswitch vSwitch1, Error: Not a valid pnic: bpvm0
```

Any Suggestions on how to get it to work?

Comment: If this update is your answer, put it in the answer section and accept it.  Answering your own question is encouraged!

Comment: No Silicom IO device has been on VMWare's HCL since v3.5 and the DL140 has never been supported with any VMWare products - why are you trying to make life hard for yourself? This site is for professional sysadmins, who'd inherently never compromise their systems stability by building an unsupported system - nobody will ever need to recreate this problem you had.

Comment: Thanks Aaron fixed the post. Chopper3 I was using old hardware laying around for a test environment. And as for the DL140 it works just fine with ESXi 5 running multiple VM used in a test environment. I am sorry that you feel that this place is not welcome for people to ask for help..... unless they in your eyes are Pro sysadmins. And you never know when any piece of information isn't helpful even if it makes you look like an idiot it may save some one else from making the same mistake.

Comment: VMWare's ESX hosts are well known for being very fussy with system components that are not on their HCL. @Chopper3 was trying to point out this fact (you know, to 'save some one else from making the same mistake', just as you wanted) so you might try being less of an ungrateful prick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard lesson to learn, in the PN if it is xxxxxxx-CS-xxxx not xxxxxxx-SD-xxxx it will not work with vmware.

Answer (score 1):

In a pinch, we know Intel and Broadcom cards will always work with VMWare/Linux/etc. and are well-supported. Recall that ESXi is a small-footprint distribution and only has native support for a limited number of devices. @chopper3 was a bit harsh, but the "professional" thing to do is to stick to the hardware compatibility list or substitute supported components as necessary.